# In F#, how do I initialize static fields in a type with no primary constructor?

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I have an F# class that derives from a .net class with multiple constructors. To expose them all, I implement a type with no primary constructor. Now I would like to add a static field. How do I initialize the static field? Consider this:

```
type MyType =
    inherit DotNetType
    [<DefaultValue>] static val mutable private myStatic : int
    new () = { inherit DotNetType() }
    new (someArg:string) = { inherit DotNetType(someArg) }
```

Now, how do I initialize the "myStatic" field in a way that runs exactly once if the type is used, and not at all if the type is never used? Essentially, I need the equivalent of a C# static constructor block.

Comment: Would that solve your problem: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483473.aspx ?

Comment: No, it wouldn't because my type does not have a primary constructor. A "static do" gets me this error:
    "Static value definitions may only be used in types with a primary constructor. Consider adding arguments to the type definition, e.g. 'type X(args) = ...'."
Thanks for the reply, though.

Answer (score 6):

See the [F# spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/), section *8.6.3 Additional Object Constructors in Classes*:

> For classes without a primary constructor, side effects can be
>   performed after the initialization of the fields of the object by
>   using the `additional-constr-expr then stmt` form.

Example:

```
type MyType  =
    inherit DotNetType
    [<DefaultValue>] static val mutable private myStatic : int
    new () = { inherit DotNetType() } then MyType.myStatic <- 1
    new (someArg:string) = { inherit DotNetType(someArg) }
    static member Peek = MyType.myStatic

MyType.Peek |> printfn "%d" // prints 0
MyType() |> ignore
MyType.Peek |> printfn "%d" // prints 1
```

Comment: But that runs the logic once per call to the constructor, not once per initialization of the type itself.

Comment: @kvb It runs the code _after_ initialization for each call to the constructor, whereas `static do` statements from primary constructors run at startup, independent of any call to a constructor.
Therefore, neither emulates the behaviour of a [C# static constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) which runs _before_ the first instance is created. The `additional-constr-expr then stmt` form allows at least some control to come close.

Answer (score 3):

I had same wondering as the OP and I didn't like the only accepted answer. In my case what I ended up doing is just use a normal field (via `let`) inside a `module` element, instead of a `type` one.